# stochastic differential equation with inverse mean

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Now I try to **solve the following stochastic differential equation**:
$$
dX_t = \alpha \frac{1}{X_t} dt + \beta dB_t,
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are some constants.

Can anyone help me with the above SDE?

Note that $X_t \ge 0$.